# Can't boot into UBUNTU, after Yosemite install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, macosx

I have posted on here as a last resort as I have searched for a solution and haven't been able to find one.

I recently installed OS X Yosemite on my mac. Since then I have not been able to gain access to UBUNTU using refInd. I reinstalled refInd and also removed the logical drive.

The boot menu appears now, but when I try and boot into UBUNTU from the hard drive, I get 'No Bootable Drive' and when I try and boot UBUNTU from a USB stick I get 'Alloc Magic is Broken ...'.

I'm not sure what the next step is. If anyone could share some insight would be highly appreciated.

Cheers,

I was able to boot into UBUNTU with a live CD, I think my USB was corrupted. However, still can not get into the one on the HD. :( Am looking into some boot up disk now to see if that works.

Here is the list of partitions: I deleted the logical drive, ,dunno if it was a good thing or not.

```
    /dev/disk0

       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0

       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

       2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                400.6 GB   disk0s2

       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

       4:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4

       5:       Microsoft Basic Data                         1.0 MB     disk0s5

       6: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               93.8 GB    disk0s6

       7:                 Linux Swap                         4.2 GB     disk0s7
```

Comment: Check your partitions from OS X and post your results in your question please.

Comment: I have updated the post with the results. :)

Comment: Everything I would suggest, you've probably already tried, like going in and deleting all the refind files, then reinstalling...  what was on the logical drive?

Comment: And when you say you removed the logical drive do you mean you physically removed a hard drive from your computer?  If you physically removed a hard drive from your computer then that's probably the culprit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say logical volume.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and was able to get past the 'no boot device' using tips from refind and the Web. Basically it consisted of moving some refind EFI folders and files around. I'll try to post the link.

But even getting Ubuntu to allow me to choose kernel, it continues to fail to mount /dev, /sys, & /proc so I'm stuck again.

Strangely I am unable to boot using USB or DVD as it seems to launch an illegal video mode and scrambles the screen.

Good luck!

Comment: I ended up deleting refind then reinstalling it, and shifting a few files around. I eventually was able to log back into UBUNTU. The only downside is that it take around 20 - 30 seconds to load up refind you have to press the alt/option key then press the efi boot which eventually goes into refind, after which you can load UBUNTU from there. Its pretty tedious, I'm about to get rid of OS X all together I think and just run it as a Linux machine. If you find anything that allows it to work  as before please let me know. Good Luck :)